# Python classes and errors

Tags: python, class, methods, error-handling

Working on some homework for a while now and can't seem to figure out how to get around this error. Just to note, I am not allowed to import anything.

The error I am getting I think is due to either my `__repr__` or `__str__` methods. Here is my code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        """
        The constructor allows the user to set values for x and y. Default values are 0.
        """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def translate(self, s, t):
        """
        This method translates point x by s and point y by t.
        """
        self.x = self.x + s
        self.y = self.y + t
        return self.x, self.y

    def __str__(self):
        """
        This method returns a string representation of the point.
        """
        return "({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        This method returns a string representation of the point.
        """
        return "({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)

class SimplePoly:
    def __init__(self, *vertices):
        """
        The constuctor adds all vertices to a list.
        """
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.pointlist = [self.vertices]

    def translate(self, s, t):
        """
        This method translates all points of the polygon by (s,t).
        """
        for p in self.pointlist:
            p.x + s
            p.y + t
        print(self.pointlist)
```

but when I try to do translate to every Point object in the self.pointlist, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#170>", line 1, in <module>
    h.translate(1,1)
  File "C:/Python34/problem2.py", line 74, in translate
    p.x + s
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'
```

The vertices are Point objects. This is the code I am testing with:

```
>>> g = Point(2,3)
>>> g2 = Point(5,2)
>>> g3 = Point(6,7)
>>> h = SimplePoly(g,g2,g3)
>>> h.translate(1,1)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using for testing?

Comment: What makes you think it is the `__str__` or `__repr__`? You are calling `h.translate()` here.

Comment: This is the code I am testing with: g = Point(2,3) >>> g2 = Point(5,2) >>> g3 = Point(6,7) >>> h = SimplePoly(g,g2,g3) >>> h.translate(1,1) my professor told me that it doesn't need to equate to an actual polygon, it can just be some arbitrary points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.pointlist` attribute is a list with *one* tuple in it:

```
def __init__(self, *vertices):
    # ....
    self.vertices = vertices
    self.pointlist = [self.vertices]
```

`vertices` is always a tuple here, which in turn contains your `Point()` objects. Tuples never have `x` and `y` attributes; it is itself not a `Point` instance.

You may as well replace `self.pointlist` with `self.vertices` here. If you needed a mutable sequence, use `list()` instead of a list literal:

```
self.pointlist = list(self.vertices)
```

which creates a list with the elements from the tuple.

Comment: The vertices are Point objects. This is the code I am testing with: g = Point(2,3)
>>> g2 = Point(5,2)
>>> g3 = Point(6,7)
>>> h = SimplePoly(g,g2,g3)
>>> h.translate(1,1)
my professor told me that it doesn't need to equate to an actual polygon, it can just be some arbitrary points

Comment: @flarp: right, but `pointlist` is a list object with just one element, a tuple, where the tuple contains your `Point()` objects. If you needed it to be a list of the points, then use `list(vertices)`.